# How to use pypdf2 to check if a pdf password is correct

Tags: python, python-3.x, pypdf

I am doing a challenge problem from Automate the Boring Stuff with Python. The task is to write a program that will "brute force" a pdf password using a provided dictionary.txt file.

Using a file I encrypted and know the password to, and a dictionary file that contains that password, I cannot get my code to "figure out" that it is the password. Instead it runs until the end of the dictionary file, then stops.

I thought I might be misunderstanding how pdfObject.decrypt() would work in an "if" statement, so I made a little test program to play with the syntax, but it works in that program using the same syntax as my "main" program. In the "test" program I provide the password from input() instead of argv and a list, but I can't see if/how that's affecting it.

```
#My Program (that blitzes right past the correct password):

#/usr/bin/python

# bruteForce.py - Uses a dictionary attack to crack the password of an
# encrypted pdf

from sys import argv
import PyPDF2

# Take the argument for the file you want to attack and open it
if len(argv) > 1:
    pdfFilename = argv[1]
else:
    print('User must specify a file.')
    exit()

# Open the pdf as an object
pdfFile = open(pdfFilename, 'rb')
pdfObject = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)

# Add the contents of the dictionary file to a data structure
dictionaryList = []
dictionaryFile = open('dictionary.txt')
for word in dictionaryFile.readlines():
    dictionaryList.append(word)
    wordLower = word.lower()
    dictionaryList.append(wordLower)
dictionaryFile.close()

# Iterate over the data structure, trying each password as lowercase
print('Trying passwords...')
for word in dictionaryList:
    password = str(word)
    print('Trying ' + password)
    if pdfObject.decrypt(password) == 1:
        print('Password is ' + word)
        exit()
    else:
        continue

print('Password not found')

##My Test (that works and returns 'Yup, that's it!'):

#!/usr/bin/python
# Figuring out how to deal with foo.decrypt to get a value of 1 or 0
# This first test returns the correct result with the correct password,
# so presumably bruteForce is not feeding it the right password somehow

import PyPDF2

filename = input('What file?')
password = input('What password?')

pdfFile = open(filename, 'rb')
pdfObject = PyPDF2.PdfFileReader(pdfFile)

if pdfObject.decrypt(password) == 1:
    print('Yup, that\'s it!')
else:
    print('Nope!')



I expect the program to arrive at the correct word in the dictionary, try it, and stop. Instead, it runs to the end of the list and says "Password not found."
```

Comment: One thing to look at might be if the password is a string or a unicode object in the different versions

Comment: @Pengman Thanks for your response. I thought of the same thing (specifically that I might need to make sure it's a string) and added `password = str(word)` instead of using `word` directly from the if statement. Does that not guarantee that the value of `password` is a string?

Comment: You're right of course. Another thing to look at is that readlines seems to include the trailing newlines for the lines (i'm looking at [this link](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/file_readlines.htm)). That might not be the case for _input_

Comment: @Pengman Thanks, I saw that there were spaces between the lines on the command line output but I'm still enough of a novice to be unsure about what's normal. I added a line `wordStripped = word.strip('\n')` in the for loop that populates the list, and it worked. Thank you for your idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The dictionary entries contained the newlines from the text file, so they weren't matching the password. I stripped them with `wordStripped = word.strip('\n')` before adding them to the dictionary and the program worked as expected (and about twice as fast).

Answer (score 0):

if you use;

```
word_list = open("dictionary.txt").readlines()
```

Then the list only contains the words, you can test this by printing out each line from the list with;

The make the project work I used the .strip method to remove the '\n' as I iterated through the list