# PyPDF2 - attempting decryption

Tags: python, encryption, pypdf

Attempting the practise case from automate the boring stuff for decrypting a pdf, guessing the password by using words from a dictionary. I've added a short list of 4 passwords to try out. My code runs, just never prints the message that it found the password, which decrypted the file. I used "password" to encrypt the pdf, so there should definetely be a match.

Various solutions on the web for the same problem set use code along the lines of "if reader.decrypt(i) == 1:" - just like my script. Not sure where the problem lies. The password on the file is definitely "password" and works everytime I open the file manually. Thank you for any help you can provide.

- https://github.com/IanFindlay/automate-the-boring-stuff-projects/blob/master/Chapter%2013/pdf_pass_break.py
- [How to use pypdf2 to check if a pdf password is correct](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55953752/how-to-use-pypdf2-to-check-if-a-pdf-password-is-correct)

  ```
   from PyPDF2 import PdfReader

   #opening the encrypted pdf and starting the trials:
   reader = PdfReader("15_Practise_Brute_Force.pdf")

   #passwords to try out
   pw = ["cake", "mother", "password", "star"]

   for i in pw:           
       print(i)
       if reader.decrypt(i) == 1:
           print("Password is: ", i)
  ```

Comment: There are two different password types, which will return 1 or 2.  I suggest you simply use `if reader.decrypt(i):`

Comment: Ugh, they [might have documented this](https://github.com/py-pdf/pypdf/blob/main/pypdf/_encryption.py#L892)

Comment: Thank you, that fixed it! I am a beginner and working through "Automate the boring stuff", which is not easy in self study and the code no longer working as described in the book. I guess story of a developers life ;-) So thank you to all of you that take the time to answer my (probably silly) questions. You are really helping me learn.

Comment: You should use pypdf. [PyPDF2 is deprecated](https://pypi.org/project/PyPDF2/). I am the maintainter of both libraries. [pypdf supports AES encryption+decryption](https://pypdf.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/encryption-decryption.html), PyPDF2==3.0.0 only decryption.